# How to combine three patterns of regex together?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to pattern together

```
1. Is
2. (https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})  -website regex pattern
3. down?
```

all into one, I tried

```
/(Is(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})\sdown?)/
```

but nothing matches.

What I expect to output is

> Is http://yahoo.com down? // returns true

Comment: add `\s*` after `Is`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var patterns = [
  /Is/,
  /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})/,
  /down\?/
];

var delimiter = /\s+/;  // or / / to match single spaces only

var re = new RegExp(patterns.map(pattern => pattern.source).join(delimiter.source));

console.log(re);
console.log(re.test('Is http://yahoo.com down?'));
console.log(re.test('Is http://socks.com down?'));
```

Comment: If a pattern is known beforehand, a regex literal notation is preferred. See my answer with a regex literal notation. BTW, arrow functions are not supported by IE browser, I think. Anyway, a good answer.

Comment: Of course, but I would still be interested to hear if there is a more elegant way to programatically join regex?

Answer (score 1):

You just need the `\s*` between the parts, or `\W+` if there can also be some punctuation:

```
/Is\s*(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s.]+\.\S{2,}|www\.\S+\.\S{2,})\s*down\?/
   ^^^                                                              ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qU7eX6/1)

Also, `[^\s]` = `\S`.

```js
var s = "Is http://www.socks.com down?";
var re = /Is\s*(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s.]+\.\S{2,}|www\.\S+\.\S{2,})\s*down\?/;
console.log(re.test(s));
```